# RestEasy Scanners breaking Tomcat Application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, resteasy, web.xml

here the RestEasy filter which is being extended by RestListener is nreaking up the application after upgrading the version of log4j from 1.x version to 2.x verison, Kindly help stuck on this issue for last 2 weeks,

```
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.avanza.ambit.filter.RestListener]
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to scan WEB-INF for JAX-RS annotations, you must manually register your classes/resources
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap.createDeployment(ConfigurationBootstrap.java:177)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ListenerBootstrap.createDeployment(ListenerBootstrap.java:32)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:27)
            at com.avanza.ambit.filter.RestListener.contextInitialized(RestListener.java:50)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1671)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
            at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
            at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
            at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:459)
            at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:408)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
            at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
```

Comment: RestEasy probably is using Log4j as well, perhaps try upgrading RESTeasy dependency as well and see if that resolves you problem.

Comment: @SMA I updated resteasy from 2.x version to 3.x version, which depreciates the many functions which are still on use.